# How can I get the output from PowerShell's Format-List as a string?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to write the output from a Format-List command to the event log so I need it as a string.

Is there a generic way to do this that doesn't depend on knowing what is being formatted?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `Out-String` cmdlet:

```
... | Format-List | Out-String
```

Comment: Ah.  Just when I'm railing about how complicated everything is in PowerShell, it's not.  Thanks very much.